# Higher Order Function Syntax in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm teaching myself Common Lisp using Norvig's Paradigms of AI Programming and came across something I didn't understand and he didn't explain.

```
(defun mappend (fn the-list)
  (apply #'append (mapcar fn the-list)))
```

What is the difference between calling a higher order function as follows, `higherOrderFunc #'funcName funcArg` and what he does when calling `mapcar` without `#'`?  Is `#'` necessary when calling a higher order function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Common Lisp has different namespaces for functions and variables.

```
(defun mappend (fn the-list)
   (apply #'append (mapcar fn the-list)))
```

Above `MAPPEND` gets defined with two local variables `fn` and `the-list`

`APPLY` gets passed the *function* value of `APPEND`.

`MAPCAR` gets passed the *variable* value of `FN`.

Similar see this:

```
CL-USER 129 >  (flet ((add-something (number)
                       (+ number 17)))
                (let ((add-something (lambda (number)
                                       (+ number 42))))
                  (list
                   (mapcar #'add-something '(1 2 3))
                   (mapcar add-something '(1 2 3)))))

->

((18 19 20) (43 44 45))
```

`LET` creates local variables, `FLET` creates local functions.

The first `mapcar` uses the function namespace and the second uses the variable namespace.

Common Lisp uses a special function namespace because it was thought to be more efficient (slightly easier to implement a fast Lisp) and to allow functions and variables to have the same name.

In Common Lisp we can write:

```
(defun list-me (list)
  (list list))
```

In Scheme, which does not have separate namespaces one would write something like this:

```
(define (list-me lst)
  (list lst))
```

Comment: Can you explain the use of 'flet' and how it differs from 'let'?  It seems define the scope of some temporary function in the way that 'let' defines the scope of some temporary variable.

Comment: One small addition to Rainer's answer in order to clarify a point that's implicit in it: When you call `mappend`, you need to pass the function argument as `#'some-func`.  That gets the function value of the symbol `some-func`, which is then passed into `mappend` as the value of `fn`.

Answer (score 6):

`#'` is syntactic sugar for `function`: `#'foo` is read as `(function foo)`.

`Function` is a special operator that returns the function value bound to the name given.  If you pass a function as a parameter, that parameter (in your case, `fn`) has its value bound to the function.  To pass it on to another function, you can simply put the variable name into the call form.  However, to get the function value of a name, you need to access it with `function`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `#'` is not strictly required.  If instead you simply pass `'foo` the symbol-function will be invoked.  Consider the following:

```
* (defvar foo #'(lambda (a) 'var))
* (setf (symbol-function 'foo) #'(lambda (a) 'fun))

* (mapcar 'foo '(a b))
(FUN FUN)

* (mapcar #'foo '(a b))
(FUN FUN)

* (mapcar foo '(a b))
(VAR VAR)
```

Practially #'foo or 'foo are equivalent:

> X3J13 voted [...] to allow the 'function' to the only of type 'symbol'
>   or 'function'; [...] one must use the 'function' special form [...]
>   before a lambda-expression [...].

Specification of the function in `flet` has some interesting properties:

```
* (flet ((foo (a) 'FLET))
    (mapcar foo '(a b)))           ; Uses 'value' of foo
(VAR VAR)

* (flet ((foo (a) 'FLET))
    (mapcar 'foo '(a b)))          ; Uses 'function' of foo
(FUN FUN)

* (flet ((foo (a) 'FLET))
    (mapcar #'foo '(a b)))         ; Uses local binding 'flet' of foo
(FLET FLET)
```

Comment: Do not do this, however; `#'foo` and `'foo` are no more equivalent than `(function foo)` and `(quote foo)`. That is to say, not very, even if they can be used in some of the same circumstances. Either way, using quoted symbols obscures the meaning of your code.

Comment: Not for local functions. `(flet ((foo () 'bar)) (funcall 'foo))` does not work. Additionally there might be slight differences when using an optimizing compiler between `(funcall (function bar))` and (funcall 'bar)). It's likely that the latter will always lookup the function via the symbol, while the first may see the lookup optimized away and using the current (during compilation) function binding during. A file compiler might want to do that. So: to be consistent using `FUNCTION` or `#'` is preferred. If you want late binding of global functions, use the symbol.

Comment: Updated with `flet` use.  Note: I agree use `#'` but my choice was not what was asked in the OQ.